# What causes -[__NSArrayM removeAllItems]: unrecognized selector while using Kal?

Tags: objective-c, kal

I have been working with Kal for 3 weeks. I was able to *modify* the holiday example to use my data and drill down. I am trying to *create* the *simplest* working process to build on.

I can display the calendar but when I try to mark dates I get an exception error:

On first starting this process I had a error about the delegate 
 I read that I needed to change from this

```
 */
 @interface KalViewController : UIViewController <KalViewDelegate, KalDataSourceCallbacks>
 {
   KalLogic *logic;
   UITableView *tableView;
   id <UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
   id <KalDataSource> dataSource;
   NSDate *initialDate;                    // The date that the calendar was initialized with *or* the currently selected date when the view hierarchy was torn down in order to satisfy a low memory warning.
   NSDate *selectedDate;                   // I cache the selected date because when we respond to a memory warning, we cannot rely on the view hierarchy still being alive, and thus we cannot always derive the selected date from KalView's selectedDate property.
  }

   @property (nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) id<KalDataSource> dataSource;
   @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSDate *selectedDate;
```

TO THIS

```
 @interface KalViewController : UIViewController <KalViewDelegate, KalDataSourceCallbacks>
 {
 KalLogic *logic;
  UITableView *tableView;
 __weak id <UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
 __weak id <KalDataSource> dataSource;
NSDate *initialDate;                    // The date that the calendar was initialized with *or* the currently selected date when the view hierarchy was torn down in order to satisfy a low memory warning.
 NSDate *selectedDate;                   // I cache the selected date because when we respond to a memory warning, we cannot rely on the view hierarchy still being alive, and thus we cannot always derive the selected date from KalView's selectedDate property.
```

}

```
 //@property (nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
 //@property (nonatomic, weak) id <UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
 //@property (nonatomic, weak) id <KalDataSource> dataSource;
 @property ( weak) id <UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
 @property ( weak) id <KalDataSource> dataSource;
 @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSDate *selectedDate;
```

Is this Correct Incorrect way of getting out of the delegate error?

Comment: Where are you calling `removeAllItems` from? Also, by the way, your code has a lot of redundant calls in it.

Comment: @Garrett kalDataSource.m calls removeAllItems

Comment: I removed some of the redundancy and reposted.

Comment: The `dataSource` property of `KalViewController` expects an object that conforms to `<KalDataSource>`. A NSMutableArray does not conform to this protocol. **Please don't ignore compiler warnings.** Most compiler warnings lead to runtime bugs, like in this case. The warnings are there for a reason.

Comment: Does this code show any warnings when you compile it?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch exactly what I was thinking

Comment: Thank you Matthias but I can't see it.   So I'm supposed to recreate KalDataSource in this viewcontroller?  protocol KalDataSource <NSObject, UITableViewDataSource>
- (void)presentingDatesFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate delegate:(id<KalDataSourceCallbacks>)delegate;
- (NSArray *)markedDatesFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate;
- (void)loadItemsFromDate:(NSDate *)fromDate toDate:(NSDate *)toDate;
- (void)removeAllItems;
end
Can't supply it with dates?

Comment: what's the type of `dataSource` in your class? If you don't see warnings about `assigning to 'id<KalDataSource>' from incompatible type 'NSMutableArray'` you probably made it `id` so you don't see warnings. Start by getting rid of that instance variable and use `calendar.dataSource = myArray;` directly. But this will only help you to see the warnings. Maybe you should have another look at the Kal examples.

Comment: exactly. You have to provide an object that conforms to `<KalDataSource>`. Maybe you should have another look at the Kal examples.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch with that change I do get Assigning to 'id<KalDataSource>' from incompatible type 'NSMutableArray *__strong'

Comment: Been looking at it for three weeks - tried tapku - tried two others. I obviously a rookie at Xcode but everything seems hopelessly redundant. Thank you for your attempt and your time.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch read that to get rid of the delegate error

Comment: Reposted   Is this the situation Matthias was talking about? Should I use the __weak description